# PHP using $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] and relative or absolute paths

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm  using XAMMP and using this variable in my index.php pages:

```
($_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/path/to/my/php/file);"
```

My file structure is like so located in the htdocs folder:

```
myprojectnet/include

   myprojectnet/css

      myprojectnet/js

        myprojectnet/folder1/index.php, css folder and js folder, etc;

            myprojectnet/folder2/index.php css folder and js folder, etc;
```

Inside my index.php files I've used this variable:

```
($_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/header.php");
```

Inside my header.php file the structure is like so:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/name.css">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I'm having to put my css folder and js folder inside the same directories where my index.php file resides and I shouldn't have to do this when my header.php file should be resolving the path to my css folder and js folder correctly.

Comment: Can you please, describe the path to css and js file as relative to php index.php, that where you want to keep them and where index.php is.

Comment: Also please add a bit of code snippet from where you are using this. Personally, I've never used DOCUMENT_ROOT superglobal for referencing where all my js and css files are located for html output to the browser. So I'm curious how you are using it.

Comment: Differentiate between the server-side file system, and the website URL structure. The latter can overlap with the former, but `$_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` will hardly ever have anything to do with client-side URLs.

Comment: @CBroe my css folder &  JS folder reside in the root of my public_html directory. So file structure is as so: public_html/css; public_html/JS folders, then I have folders: public_html/folder1/index.php; public_html/folder2/index.php and so on. But PHP doesn't see it this way as my includes folder that holds my header, sidebar and footer php files also reside in the root of public_html. PHP is telling me that my css and js files should be INSIDE the same directory where my index.php file resides

Comment: ($_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/header.php");

Comment: _"PHP is telling me that my css and js files should be INSIDE the same directory where my index.php file resides"_ - and how exactly is PHP "telling" you that? Why would PHP care what goes on on the client side in the first place?

Comment: If your main problem is that your HTML documents are spread over several different folder levels, but you want them to refer the same CSS/JS resources, then you can also simply link those relative to the domain root, with a leading slash.

Comment: @CBroe correct. I have one folder level, never going more than two for now. I need an absolute path to my css and js folders on the root when the folder is on a different level than my includes folder. When I view the source to the page (hover my mouse over the js/jquery.js link) and view the path on the bottom of my browswer, it's looking for the  js/jquery.js and CSS folder inside the same directory where my index.php file resides, which tells me that the global variable I'm using  is not, in anyway making an absolute path to my files on the root directory.

Comment: _"I need an absolute path to my css and js folders on the root"_ - as I said, leading slash - `/js/jquery.js`

Comment: @CBroe, it still doesn't resolve to my CSS files, BUT it will to my JS files when using  "../js/jquery.js. I put the same ../ to my css files and it won't find them.

Comment: @CBroe I'm using xammp and my root is "myprojectsnet" under the htdocs folder. So therefore in my header.php file, I must put the the two dot ("../") before the leading slash.

Comment: If you use `../`, then it will only work for HTML documents from one specific folder level again. Where are your CSS and JS files located, in relation to the `public_html` directory? And it `myprojectsnet` inside that? Please lay out the folder structure properly, edit your question, so that we don't have to piece all this partially from different comments.

Comment: @CBroe edited the question

Comment: _"BUT it will to my JS files when using "../js/jquery.js. I put the same ../ to my css files and it won't find them"_ - that makes _no sense_ then with the folder structure you have shown. If the js and the css folder are located on the same level, then ../ also has to work the same way for both of them.

Comment: @CBroe, I know and I've checked everthying out. I can remove the js folder from the directory and it works fine, but when I remove the CSS folder, it doesn't load the stylesheet; and I even did a hard reset in chrome to clear out the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that all `js` and `css` files are in `root/assets/css` and `root/assets/js`. And all php files are in like `root/main/index.php` or `root/other/index.php`, you can simply use something like this:

```
$baseDir = dirname(__DIR__);

$cssFile = $baseDir."/assets/css/style.css";

$jsFile = $baseDir."/assets/js/index.js";
```

Comment: `dir(__DIR__)` not just `__DIR__` ??

Comment: So making a variable and creating the value to the directories in this way, becomes an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: @mega6382 this didn't seem to work for me... my file structure in xammp is as such - htdocs/myprojectnet (root)/css, js, and includes foders. Then my directories.